# Get triangular wave on pspice

Tags: wave, integrator, pspice

I designed a integrator op-amp on pspice. I want to get triangular waves for output and square waves for input.

Input is OK, but I can't get triangular waves.

[image]

What is wrong, should I use a second op-amp?

thats the schematic. red one is the input green one is the output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the op-amp wired incorrectly. Negative feedback is needed and this means swapping pins 2 and 3.

You also have a positive voltage for both pos and neg supply voltages!

A tip for asking questions in future - when you say you can't get triangle waves you do have to normally explain what you actually see - this is important.

Be prepared for a non-ideal triangle wave due to the 100k feedback resistor - it will round the linear ramps of the triangle wave a tad. Maybe try 1Mohm to improve this but watch out for the op-amp's output drifting towards one of the supply rails and possibly clipping the waveform on the output.

Comment: thanks but when i swap, the Voutput is zero

Comment: Read my full answer.

Comment: sorry i didnt see :) thanks again but upper voltage is + and down is - . they are no both positive. i shared on link what i actually see i couldnt copy it here. could you please check? thanks

Comment: @GizemÖnen I'm not going to open a docx document for what should be fairly obvious reasons. Try posting an image of the circuit.

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: Now that you've fixed the input reversal, a zero output suggests that you did not correctly connect your input resistor.